# Add custom AMI to the list of Parameters

Tags: aws-cloudformation

This part of cloudformation template works as expected:

```
Parameters:
  LatestAmiId:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    Default: /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn-ami-hvm-x86_64-ebs
```

But when I changed it to something like this, I get an error:

```
Parameters:
  LatestAmiId:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    Default: /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn-ami-hvm-x86_64-ebs
    AllowedValues:
      - /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn-ami-hvm-x86_64-ebs
      - ami-XXadfa6e17bbca4XX
```

I want to allow 2 values for LastestAmiId field. I will use this value in Properties:

```
  MySpotFleet:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SpotFleet'
    Properties:
      SpotFleetRequestConfigData:
        LaunchSpecifications:
          - ImageId: !Ref LatestAmiId
```

This works if I keep only 1 SSM Parameter value as shown above. But how do I allow my custom AMI along with default AMI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you can't do this, since `ami-XXadfa6e17bbca4XX` is **not the type** of `AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>`.

You need to have **two separate parameters**, e.g. `LatestAmiId` and `LatestAmiId2` with their respective types. Then use conditions in your template to choose between the one which is selected by the user.